# Cronexpression to exclude hours of a specific day

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Is it possible to create a CronExpression with:
"fire every day every 20min but not on Saturday between 10:00 and 14:00"?

Something like "0 0/20 * ? * MON-SAT" is clear, but it is not the same...

Answer (score 8):

You will have to use two expressions; One for saturdays, one for all other days:

```
0 0/20 * * * SUN-FRI     command
0 0/20 0-9,14-23 * * SAT command
```